# How do I fix this error about endpoints when opening WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an Ubuntu distro with WSL for my Windows laptop, it used to work fine until a couple days ago and can´t seem to fix it.

I get this message

```
There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
Press any key to continue...
```

I don't even know what that means. I have a bunch of programming assignments done inside and don't want to loose them.

How can I fix this issue so I can use WSL?

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: That looks like a Windows error not an Ubuntu error - perhaps this will set you in the right direction? [WSL 2 errors when ICS is disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#wsl-2-errors-when-ics-is-disabled)